# Convert array of strings to an array of integers

Tags: ruby

I need to convert strings in an array representing numbers into integers.

```
["", "22", "14", "18"]
```

into

```
[22, 14, 18]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: With empty values it would require an extra operation, maybe like `["", "22", "14", "18"].reject(&:empty?).map(&:to_i)`.

Comment: @SebastianPalma why dont you answer?

Comment: @SebastianPalma I'm not sure he needs any special operation, as rails will convert empty string to `0` when you use `to_i` so `["", "22", "14", "18"].map(&:to_i)` should be enough! (The result will be: `[0, 22, 14, 18]`, so if you don't want a `0` in the result, you do need the extra operation)

Comment: I think maybe Integer#to_i is implemented in Ruby as in Rails, in both cases it returns 0, but the output added doesn't contain a 0 as first value, that's why, it lacks info.

Comment: Core implements `String#to_i`

Comment: @SebastianPalma oh i missed the wanted output :S

Comment: You're right @JoshBrody, `String#to_i` I meant (as `''` => string) C:

Answer (score 45, accepted):

To convert a string to number you have the `to_i` method.

To convert an array of strings you need to go through the array items and apply `to_i` on them. You can achieve that with `map` or `map!` methods:

```
> ["", "22", "14", "18"].map(&:to_i)
# Result: [0, 22, 14, 18]
```

Since don't want the `0` - just as @Sebastian Palma said in the comment, you will need to use an extra operation to remove the empty strings: (The following is his answer! Vote for his comment instead :D)

```
> ["", "22", "14", "18"].reject(&:empty?).map(&:to_i)
# Result: [22, 14, 18]
```

the difference between `map` and `map!` is that `map` will return a new array, while `map!` will change the original array.

Comment: If using Rails compact_blank will make it work if the array contains a mix of integers and strings e.g. `["", "22", "14", "18" ,123].compact_blank.map(&:to_i)`

Answer (score 6):

You could select the strings containing digits using [`grep`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep):

```
["", "22", "14", "18"].grep(/\d+/)
#=> ["22", "14", "18"]
```

And convert them via [`to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-to_i) by passing a block to `grep`:

```
["", "22", "14", "18"].grep(/\d+/, &:to_i)
#=> [22, 14, 18]
```

Depending on your input, you might need a more restrictive pattern like `/\A\d+\z/`.

Comment: This is super nice but it is worth noting that if the array already contains integers it will reject them.

Comment: @rmaspero true, but the OP specifically asked to _"Convert array of strings to an array of integers"_, hence the use of `grep` and a regular expression. Handing mixed arrays is something else.