# How to remove double quotes from ruby array

Tags: ruby

I am facing an issue converting ruby array `["1", "2"]` to [1,2]

we can use ["1", "2"].map{|n| eval n} but the use of eval is a serious security risk.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Like `map(&:to_i)`?

Comment: Another suggestion would be to start thinking in the correct terms ASAP. There's no such thing as "remove double quotes from array". This array does not contain any quotes. It contains some strings, though. And these strings look like numbers. So you want an array of actual numbers. So, a better question would be "how to convert array of strings to array of integers in ruby". Et voilà, it's already been answered: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48412311/125816

Comment: What do you mean by "removing quotes"? There are no quotes in your array. Do you want to parse strings containing integers?

Answer (score 2):

Just use:

```
["1", "2"].map(&:to_i)
#=> [1, 2]
```

Which is basically the same as

```
["1", "2"].map { |number| number.to_i }
```

See [`Array#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.1.3/Array.html#method-i-map) and [`String#to_i`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.1.3/String.html#method-i-to_i).